# How to show a specific html elements for specific authorized users in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, social-networking

I am building very very simple soical network and here is my question: 
For example I want to show a button "Change profile picture" on user's page only for user which owns this profile and should be hidden for other authorized users. Any suggestions?

Here is my Login method:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(LoginModel user)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (IsValid(user.UserName, user.Password))
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.UserName, false);
                    return RedirectToAction("About", "User", new{ username = user.UserName });
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Login data is incorrect");
                }
            }
            return View(user);
        }

LoginModel:
    public class LoginModel
    {
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 6)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [StringLength(100)]
        [Display(Name = "User name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
    }
```

And the route for user profiles:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "User",
    url: "{UserName}",
    defaults: new
    {
        controller = "User",
        action = "About",
        id = UrlParameter.Optional
    });
```

Comment: My suggestion is a lot more info and some code. How do people log in? Username and password? Where do you store it? When people log in how do you maintain who they are as they move from page to page? GUIDs buried in a querystring - sessions - cookies?

Comment: Yes, it depends of that. Wee can't just give you answer without knowing how you implement your login phase.

Comment: Thatnk you. I added some information, check it out please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply set a variable from the Model in the Controller indicating that you want to show a particular part of the html.

Sample:

In your model add a property:

```
public TestModel
{
    public bool ShowContentX {get;set;}
}
```

In your Controller, fill it and pass the model to the View:

```
TestModel t = new TestModel();
t.ShowContentX = true; // create check here.

return View(t);
```

In your View, check if the property is `true`:

```
@if (@model.ShowContentX) {
  <p>add your html</p>
}
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. But before I guess I need to check whether current profile page belongs to that user. Actualy that's I would like to know, how can I do that, or there are some other ways.

Comment: I guess you have an action in your Controller accepting the id of the user belonging to that profile. You can cross-check that with the current user id / username, right? You should save it somewhere.

Comment: Well of course I can do like if(@Model.UserModel.Username == User.Identity.Name) { Html.Partial("Bla") } else { Html.Partial("Bla bla") but I really hoped that there is some other way, cause I don't wnat do like that

Comment: @AlexDefine: That should be in your model, rather than in your View, but I think you haven't got that much options for that.

Comment: Model? Did you mean controller?

Comment: You should set the value of a Model property in the Controller. Logic should be avoided as much as possible in Views.

Comment: Ok. I got it, thank you. But still would it be a good way to do this? I hoped that there is kind same attribute like [Autorized] for Actions  but for html elemets. It woukld be much easier I guess..

Comment: Unfortunately, not as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

i would create a custom html helper and make helper function to only return output when a criteria is met.

In the custom helper check if user is in role or authorized then return the html from custom html helper else return empty string.

Here is an example:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/sateesh-arveti/archive/2013/09/06/custom-html-helper-methods-in-asp-net-mvc-4.aspx

also look at this nice article:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/649394/ASP-NET-MVC-Custom-HTML-Helpers-Csharp

Hope it helps.